# Setting Icons For Android Application

Tags: android, eclipse, icons, drawable

So when I start a small application for Android, (I'm Using Eclipse if that matters) I give my application a name, minimum SDK and such. Then, when it comes down to picking a launcher icon, I created an icon with 1024 x 1024 pixels using Adobe Illustrator (if I'm clearly doing something wrong say so) and export it to .png file.

When I build my android application project, the icon is copied into the different drawable folders (mdp, hdp, xhdp...). So my question is does Eclipse already change the dp of my icon to match the different size screens? And my second question is when I add other icon (not the launcher) do I have to manual change the dp and add it to the corresponding drawable folders.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

Answer (score 0):

Sort of. It's not best practice to use the set of icons automatically created by Eclipse, for the very reason you mentioned. Highest quality is always manually creating the images via photoshop/fireworks/your preferred image software following these guidelines:

http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

Comment: Those icon sets just help you have _something_ while you're testing

Comment: I get it. It makes sense. I figured that's what it was for but I had my doubts. I am using Illustrator, I'm not sure if that's the best thing for icon creating. I'm not sure how to make different dp versions of the same icon using Illustrator.

Comment: I put photoshop/fireworks because they are popular for rasters. I personally use Illustrator because I like vectors. Professionals usually start with them too I believe.